# open multiple windows when clicked on jstree node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#tree").jstree({  
         "xml_data" : {  
             "ajax" : {  
                 "url" : "jstree.xml"            
             },  

             "xsl" : "nest"

             },  
    "themes" : {  

             "theme" : "classic",  

            "dots" : true,  

             "icons" : true 

         },  
          "ui": {
            "initially_select" : [ "#1234" ] 
       },
    "search" : {  

              "case_insensitive" : true,  

                 "ajax" : {  

                     "url" : "tree.xml" 

                 }  

             }, 
    "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types", "search", "cookies"],
    "core" : { "initially_open" : [ "12345" ] } 
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
            var node_id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
            $.cookie("example", node_id, { path: '/', expires:7 });
            window.open('new.html', '_newtab','width=800,height=1000,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');

    });
```

I am trying to jstree to populate the tree and when clicked on a node, I need to fire up a new window called new.html using cookies to store the value of the node id. It works. But I need is, when clicked on the jstree node, I need a new new.html window and clicked on another node, rather than updating the new.html, I need another window with the new node_id. So, need multiple windows for each node_id using new.html. Is this possible with jquery?

Answer (score 2):

having the empty argument as below does the trick.

```
window.open('new.html', '','width=800,height=1000,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
```